# returning data table to text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i return data from my data table into the textboxes on my form?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BLL
{
    public class tickets
    {
        public DAL.TicketsDataSet.TicketDetailsDataTable GetData()
        {
            DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter TicketDetailsTableAdapter1 = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
            return TicketDetailsTableAdapter1.GetTicketDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

My TicketDetails.xsd

[image]

Comment: So you are returning dataset to your front end. Give the columns of the datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the likes of your code, you're using DataSet(xsd) in visual studio, try doing this.

1. Check if you have a Fill() command from your table 
    [image]
2. Code like this

// testdbDataSet came from here
[image]

// initialize your data table from the dataset
testdbDataSet.testtableDataTable ts = 
new WindowsFormsApplication1.testdbDataSet.testtableDataTable();
// fill your datatable using the Fill command
testtableTableAdapter.Fill(ts);
// get the record from the rowIndex and columnIndex to your textbox or string
string test = ts.Rows[0][0].ToString();`

This is how it worked in my case.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Comment: whats the point of the BLL if we are just connecting to the DAL directly... I want to use the BLL.

Comment: you're asking how to get the data from datatable to Textboxes. It's not quiet clear actually relating to BLL and DAL.

Comment: The code i posted is from my BLL.... I have my dataset in my DAL... and when i `DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter.` << i dont get the fill property showing.

Comment: the fill property should come from DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.Fill();

Comment: how does your TicketsDataSet.xsd looks like? any screenshot you can provide?

Comment: added image to my question.

Comment: I am creating Stored Procedures, not sql statements

Comment: I think the problem is the references.... i still do not see the fill properties even when i change it to SQL statements.

Comment: using DAL; <- is this what's missing? is your DAL a class library?